# Selecting data from a datatable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, datatable

I'm trying to figure out how to get the data i need from a Datatable.
I'm new to datatables and cannot figure out by reading the documentation how to properly build the needed query.

I made a test script in PowerShell that i posted below:

```
# clear the screen:
CLS

# Create the Datatable:
$dt1 = New-Object System.Data.Datatable

# Name the datatable:
$dt1.TableName = "MyTable"

# Add columns to the table:
[void]$dt1.Columns.Add("datacolumnone")
[void]$dt1.Columns.Add("datacolumntwo")
[void]$dt1.Columns.Add("datacolumnthree")

# Add data:
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 1", [string]"fact 1", [string]"purple")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 1", [string]"fact 2", [string]"black")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 1", [string]"fact 3", [string]"green")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 1", [string]"fact 4", [string]"green")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 2", [string]"fact 1", [string]"blue")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 2", [string]"fact 2", [string]"yellow")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 2", [string]"fact 3", [string]"purple")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 2", [string]"fact 4", [string]"yellow")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 3", [string]"fact 1", [string]"purple")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 3", [string]"fact 2", [string]"black")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 3", [string]"fact 3", [string]"green")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 3", [string]"fact 4", [string]"yellow")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 4", [string]"fact 1", [string]"purple")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 4", [string]"fact 2", [string]"yellow")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 4", [string]"fact 3", [string]"purple")
[void]$dt1.Rows.Add([string]"id 4", [string]"fact 4", [string]"yellow")

# Write the data to a xml and data file:
$dt1.WriteXmlSchema('.\CacheSchema.xsd')
$dt1.WriteXml(".\CacheData.xml")

##############################
# End of this script         #
# Going on with the next one #
##############################

# Set the search criteria:
$column1 = ""
$column2 = "fact 1"
$column3 = "purple"

# build the query:
$qquery1 = "
        datacolumnone like '%"+$column1+"%' 
    AND datacolumntwo like '%"+$column2+"%'
    AND datacolumnthree like '%"+$column3+"%'
";

# Create the Datatable:
$dt2 = New-Object System.Data.Datatable

# Load the data:
[void]$dt2.ReadXmlSchema(".\CacheSchema.xsd")
[void]$dt2.ReadXml(".\CacheData.xml")

# Run the query:
$dt2.Select($qquery1)
```

Now what i try to achieve is:

> 1. Find all id's (datacolumnone) from the rows that have the value: "fact 1" in "datacolumntwo" and "purple" in "datacolumnthree"
> 2. Then further filter the id's where "datacolumnone" is in the results from the query above, "datacolumntwo" is "fact 4" and
>    "datacolumnthree" is "yellow"
> 3. Then when we have the filtered id's, show the rows that have in "datacolumnone" an id from the filtered query above and in
>    "datacolumntwo" the value "fact 2"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I ended up using MSSQL as it is better documented. I still haven't figured this one out.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly, querying a DataTable is the same as selecting rows that meet certain criteria using the Pipeline:
So, query one would be:

$results1 = $dt | Where-Object {$*.datacolumntwo -eq "fact 1" -and $*.datacolumnthree -eq "purple"} | Select Id

And query2 would be:

$results2 = $dt | Where-Object {$*.datacolumnone -in $result1 -and $*.datacolumntwo -eq "fact 4" -and $_.datacolumnthree -eq "yellow"} | Select Id

or you can combine the two queries if the intermediate results are not needed.